# Que hace el casteo "getFrom()[0]"

Tags: java

Buenas tardes/Noches/Días

Soy algo novato en java, llevo pocos meses trabajando en el...básicamente es el primer lenguaje de programación al que me he dedicado,me encuentro con una duda,a que hace referencia esta especie de casteo

```
From.add(mensaje[i].getFrom()[0].toString());
```

me refiero especificamente a la parte del "**getFrom()[0]**":,)

```
try
{      

            Session sesion = Session.getInstance(prop);
            Store store = sesion.getStore("pop3");
            //Obteniendo acceso al folder
            store.connect("pop.gmail.com", correo, contraseña);
            Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            //Obteniendo los mensajes del folder abierto anteriormente
            Message[] mensaje = folder.getMessages();
            //Extrayendo los asuntos al arraylist de strings 
            Subjects = new ArrayList<>();    
            From = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mensaje.length; i++) {
                Subjects.add(mensaje[i].getSubject());
                From.add(mensaje[i].getFrom()[0].toString());

            }
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Lo primero darte la bienvenida y pedirte que por favor te pases por el Centro de Ayuda para que aprendas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y puedas aprender de que va el sitio y como puedes obtener ayuda en este. Por otra parte te recomiendo que estudies el tema de los arreglos en Java, ya que la expresión `getFrom()[0]` no es un casteo sino que se está accediendo al primer elemento del arreglo que retorna el método `getFrom()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias   :,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es un casteo estas accediendo a un arreglo, estos arreglos puedes acceder por posiciones `[0]`, algunas posiciones pueden ser *string**, puedes visualizarlas con un `toString`

Te dejo un poco de teoria:

> Un array (arreglo) es una estructura de datos que contiene una colección de datos del  mismo tipo, estas son usadas como contenedores que almacenan uno o más datos relacionados, en lugar de declarar cada dato de manera independiente.

aca algo mas completo [Link](http://codejavu.blogspot.com/2015/01/que-son-los-arreglos-en-java_14.html)